# Allow hyphens in Django Rest Framework serializer field names

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Given an OpenAPI specification that I'm writing code against that requires hyphen-case (aka kebab-case) variable names in request bodies, how should this be handled when using Django Rest Framework?

For example, a request `POST /thing` to create a Thing has this body:

```
{
    "owner-type": "platform"
}
```

But in Python, `owner-type` is not a valid variable name ("SyntaxError: can't assign to operator"), so instead `Thing` has `owner_type` in the model definition:

```py
class Thing(models.Model):
    owner_type = models.CharField(max_length=8)
```

But now the `ThingSerializer` is problematic because, again, `owner-type` is an illegal name. This is not allowed:

```py
    owner-type = serializers.CharField(...)
```

I've tried to override how the names are generated in the `ModelSerializer` by trying to adjust the field names generated by `get_fields()`, but it failed. Here's my serializer:

```py
class ThingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Thing
        fields = [
            'owner_type',
        ]

    def get_fields(self):
        fields = super().get_fields()
        out_fields = OrderedDict()
        for field_name, field in fields.items():
            out_fields[field_name.replace('_', '-')] = field
        return out_fields
```

And the error:

```
../venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py:453: in get_attribute
    return get_attribute(instance, self.source_attrs)
../venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py:101: in get_attribute
    instance = getattr(instance, attr)
E   AttributeError: 'Thing' object has no attribute 'owner-type'
```

So my question - how can I configure a DRF model serializer to allow a model's fields that contain underscore to be serialized / deserialized so that the API client sees hyphens instead of underscores? This would be a generic solution to the example above where `Thing.owner_type` should be read / writeable by passing the field `"owner-type"` in the JSON body.

I'm using latest Django and DRF on Python 3.6.

Edit 1: Clarified that ideally this would be a generic solution that translates underscores to hyphens.

Comment: Do you want to use hyphens instead of underscores for all fields? Or just for a specific one?

Comment: If you want to do this for all fields you can use a custom renderer... There are already some that convert to camel case like https://github.com/vbabiy/djangorestframework-camel-case you could adapt them to use hyphens instead.

Comment: @BernhardVallant Thanks for the comment - I've clarified in the Question. Ideally something generic - I'll check out the renders!

Comment: Using the renderers seems to only solve the problem when rendering (as the name suggests) the `Thing` to JSON - when writing the hyphenated fields are dropped: `{'owner_type': [ErrorDetail(string='This field is required.', code='required')]`

Comment: I think that a `KebabCaseJSONRenderer` would need to be combined with a `KebabCaseJSONParser` to convert hypenated values back into underscored ones.

Comment: Yes you will need a parser as well if you want to write to the API.

Answer (score 11):

You can define field name with hyphen in `fields` and map it to correct django model field by defining `source` attribute in `extra_kwargs` - see https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#additional-keyword-arguments

To answer you question you define `ThingSerializer` as bellow:

```
class ThingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Thing
        fields = [
            'owner-type',
        ]
        extra_kwargs = {
            'owner-type': {'source': 'owner_type'},
        }
```

Comment: how can I do this with non-model serializer ? any clues ?

Comment: Only `ModelSerializer` is able to do this. `Serializer` [always uses attribute name](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/7f3a3557a050147dd2420aa41d1bf7ddd7f9818e/rest_framework/serializers.py#L285-L287) as defined on class.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `to_internal_value` of Django([See in DJango **Serializer fields**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#:%7E:text=Let%27s%20look%20at%20an%20example%20of%20serializing%20a%20class%20that%20represents%20an%20RGB%20color%20value%3A)) to get the key with the hyphens and rename it.

Example:

```py
class Thing(models.Model):
    owner_type = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    
    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        data['owner_type'] = data['owner-type']
        data.pop('owner-type', None)
        return data
```

Answer (score 1):

`get_fields` is the best way to handle this, because it will also handle your validation codepath, e.g. for errors.

If you define `source` on your field, then the value of your field will read and write to the location set in `source`.

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer[User]):
    """Serialize a user to look like a JWT id token claim."""

    sub = serializers.UUIDField(read_only=True, source="username")

    # Will be renamed to cognito:groups
    groups = serializers.ListField(
        child=serializers.ChoiceField(choices=AuthGroup.choices),
        source="groups",  # Serializer will read and write from `groups`
    )

    def get_fields(self) -> dict[str, Any]:
        """Rename the groups field to cognito:groups"""

        fields = super().get_fields()
        fields["cognito:groups"] = fields.pop("groups")

        return fields
```

Answer (score -1):

**This is not useful when use models**, but answers the use of hypens in fields, change your serializer as below

```py
class ThingSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields.update({"owner-type": serializers.CharField(write_only=True)})
```

Comment: No sorry - I've tried that already. As per the docs: "The name of the attribute that will be used to populate the field." *attribute* < aka the `Thing` model - the error is `AttributeError: 'Thing' object has no attribute 'owner-type'`.

Comment: Also fails when passing data in because the `'owner_type'` field is missing: `{'owner_type': [ErrorDetail(string='This field is required.', code='required')]`

Comment: OK this is helpful. Firstly - yes this appears to work on create, so this answers part of the question. However, when doing a read, it leaves the `owner_type` key in place and does not switch it out for `owner-type` with hyphen.

Comment: E     Left contains more items:
E     {'owner_type': 'platform'}
E     Right contains more items:
E     {'owner-type': 'platform'}

Comment: And given that I'm working on an API with 20+ endpoints and probably about 10 of these hyphenated variable names, is there not a more generic way to construct a `ModelSerializer` that will convert underscores to hyphens as the data is being serialized / deserialized?