# Can I have a field name with spaces in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Is there a way to remap the names of Django Rest Framewok SerializerFields to strings that contain spaces?

I have the following sort of code:

**models.py:**

```
class Author(models.Model):
    author_name = models.CharField()
```

**serialisers.py:**

```
class AuthorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = Author
    fields = ["author_name"]
```

This will return JSON like:

```
{ "author_name": "William Shakespeare" }
```

But I want it to return JSON like:

```
{ "The Author": "William Shakespare" }
```

I know that I can use a *different* name for a serializer field using the `source` kwarg, but that still requires a valid python name.  I'm specifically wondering if I can use a name with spaces in it.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing the field name when using Django rest framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37496584/changing-the-field-name-when-using-django-rest-framework)

Comment: I didn't realize this at the time, but I could have used `extra_kwargs` as per: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59348695/1060339

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override `to_representation()` method in your serializer class. Something like this:

```
class AuthorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = Author
    fields = ["author_name"]

  def to_representation(self, obj):
    primitive_repr = super(AuthorSerializer, self).to_representation(obj)
    primitive_repr['The Author'] = primitive_repr['author_name']
    return primitive_repr
```