# Django Rest_Framework serializer label name not working

Tags: django-rest-framework, label, django-serializer

I have serializer where I am trying to give serializer fields custom name using labels. I am mentioning the label parameter but it not updating the fields label name. Is there any update in rest_framework or I am doing it wrong.

```
class TotalMarksSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    roll_number__roll_number = serializers.IntegerField(label='Roll Number')
    roll_number__first_name = serializers.CharField(label='First Name')
    roll_number__last_name = serializers.CharField(label='Last Name')
    Total_Marks = serializers.FloatField(label='Total Marks')
```

The Output I am getting:

```
[
    {
        "roll_number__roll_number": 1,
        "roll_number__first_name": "Debbie",
        "roll_number__last_name": "Gutierrez",
        "Total_Marks": 303.0
    },
```

The output I am expecting:

```
[
    {
        "Roll Number": 1,`enter code here`
        "First Name": "Debbie",
        "Last Name": "Gutierrez",
        "Total Marks": 303.0
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

DRF docs say that `label` prop is "A short text string that may be used as the name of the field in HTML form fields or other descriptive elements." ([link](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/))

To get what you want, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60954939/can-i-have-a-field-name-with-spaces-in-django-rest-framework)